# storage bucket permissions GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, roles, bucket, sa

I have a service account (editor) writer.
i added the storage.objectadmin role.

they still can't access current buckets in the project.

am I missing storage.bucketviewer or storage.buckets.get?

thanks,

J

Comment: How did you access to the bucket with your service account? Via client libraries? API? Can you share a piece of code that you use and the error code that you get?

Comment: Try `Storage Admin` instead of `Storage Object Admin`.

Comment: thanks! storage.admin won't be allowed - storage.objectadmin didn't work.
is there any other role that doesn't have (storage.legacybucketwriter) the word legacy or admin in it that has the storage.buckets.get permission? i think that will fix my issue.  thanks